# Rails Controller Saving Wrong Values to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

In my relationships_controller I have the following:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @relationship = Relationship.new

  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @relationship = Relationship.new(params[:relationship])
    @relationship.rel_id = params[:user_id]
    @relationship.user_id = current_user

    @event = Event.new
    @event.user_id = @user
    @event.user_id = current_user
    @event.m_type = 'relationship'
    @event.text = 'wants to be friends with you.'
    @event.save

    @message = Message.new
    @message.sender_id = current_user
    @message.reciever_id = @user
    @message.subject = "New Friend Request"
    @message.body = "Hello, \n I'd like to connect with you as..."
    @message.save


    if @relationship.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed Up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
 end
end
```

The events and relationship get saved with the correct values, but no matter what I do @message always gets saved with 1 for both sender_id and receiver_id. As a test I hard coded values in there and those work, so what is happening between @evernts and @message to change the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@message.sender_id = current_user.id
```

or

```
@message.sender = current_user
```

But not

```
@message.sender_id = current_user
```

You are assigning an object to an integer

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set `_id` fields to actual ActiveRecord objects instead of integers. Instead, try either this:

```
@message.sender = current_user
@message.receiver = @user
```

Or:

```
@message.sender_id = current_user.id
@message.receiver_id = @user.id
```